# Access-Control-Allow-Origin google calendar

Tags: google-chrome, calendar, google-calendar-api

Since July 2014 until yesterday I could get the feeds of my google calendar to be displayed in my webview and chrome browser desktop with no problems, everything was perfect. But today I got the message "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", I know what this message means but I want to know if Google has changed its policy to access calendar (in json format) or what has happened?

Comment: I've logged in and check my calendar and for my surprising Google advise me that they have updated new features for Google calendar like automatic local festive days are added to my personal calendar. I'm still continuing with no access to calendar feeds :-/

Comment: the example (https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/cal_sample) in the official google developers site also shows me forbiden (damn!) there's no any notification from Google !!

Comment: Which version of calendar API are you using?

Comment: I was using v2, but today I've read about v3 which has a clean version of the json functions to get calendar data, developed for v2. Now it is required to give the key API and everything goes OK again, and then you can use the parameters documented in the new API version 3 to do a request.

Comment: you might want to check out this related thread with a response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981661/fullcalendar-google-integration-returns-a-403-error

Answer (score 0):

Hey you might want to checkout this related thread with an answer:

[fullcalendar google integration returns a 403 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981661/fullcalendar-google-integration-returns-a-403-error)

Comment: Thanks Dan, I've also noted that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26980924/google-us-holidays-calendar-feed-forbidden#comment42543936_26980924 and as I've said, one must read the documentation for calendar v3 and implement the new api properly. I'd like to know why the link you pass me has almost 500 views and the mine just 25 considering both issue the same question, weird :-/ . I've fix my problem myself, I didn't read your link before Dan. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've played around with this https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list and helped me to solve my problem quickly :D enjoy